# Renaming files created by split

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have output files from `split` called

```
shivi11aa
shivi11ab
```

(etc.)

How may I rename these existing files as

```
output_1
output_2
```

(etc.)

If I have 1000 files, the last one should be `output_1000`.

Comment: I edited the question based on some of your comments.  You should have been able to do this yourself though, by pressing the [edit] link under the question. Please edit it further if it's not correct.

Comment: thanks,but n depends on the number of my ouput files

Comment: n vary with number of output files??

Comment: In my answer, the value of `n` will be incremented to whatever number of files you have that match that particular filename pattern that I use.

Comment: thank you very much and heartily thankfull

Comment: @Shivani Please also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). No need to hurry, though. Just take your time.

Comment: Also, for future reference, see this very nice writeup by Jeff, another user here: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5015

Comment: what is bash script to split input files end with string "out_root" into desired output  files .all the output files should contain equal number of lines.if three files and 200 lines  then division sholud be like 67,67and 66

Comment: the names of output files should be "out_part1_root",out_part2_root" so on

Answer (score 5):

```
n=0
for filename in shivi11*; do
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
    mv -i "$filename" "output_$n"
done
```

... where `shivi11*` is a pattern that must match all files that you'd like to rename (and nothing else).

Back up your data and test this.

---

Answer to [the original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/494010/1) (before editing it):

If you by "split" mean the `split` utility, then you may invoke the utility like this to get what you want (this assumes GNU `split` and that you'd like to split the file `file` into 20 KB bits):

```
split -b 20k -a 1 --numeric-suffixes=1 file output_
```

This creates `output_1`, `output_2` etc.

Note that since we restrict the suffix length to a single character with `-a 1`, this would not be able to split into more than 9 files.  Using e.g. `-a 2` would create files named `output_01`, `output_02` etc. up to and including `output_99`, but not `output_100`.

The `--numeric-suffixes=1` option is a GNU `split`-specific option that selects numeric suffixes starting at the given number (instead of at 0 as using `-d` would do).  Normally, `split` creates files with alphabetic suffixes.

Comment: I JUST NEED TO RENAME FILES LIKE ABC.TXT?? TO OUTPUT_1 AND HOW TO DO FOR 5 OUTPUT FILES LIKE THIS

Comment: @Shivani No need to shout.  Calmly make your question unambiguous instead. If you don't use the `split` utility, then don't mention it (which you do now with "_the output from split_"). Instead tell us what you have and what you want, and someone may be interested enough to answer.

Comment: MY QUESTION IS TO RENAME THE MULTIPLE FILES LIKE ABC.TXT TO OUTPUT_1,OUTPUT_2 AND SO ON IF I HAVE FIVE OUTPUT FILES,,PLEASE SHARE HOW TO USE MOVE COMMAND BY USING FOR LOOP IN THIS

Comment: @Shivani Unstick you CapsLock key and update your question.  Also note that we are volunteers and that this is not a code-writing service.

Comment: my question is to rename  the multiple files like abc.txt to ouput_1,output_2 and so on if i have five output files.How to use for loop for renaming.Actually i already split the files according to lines and now i want to rename them

Comment: @Shivani, Please show us the names of all the current output files, and we can show how to rename them. Otherwise we can only guess (and will probably give useless advice).

Comment: my output files like shivi11aa,shivi11ab and so on.

Comment: my only question can i use

Comment: can i use for loop to rename them

Comment: output filenames  shivi11aa,shivi11ab and so on.i  want out_part_1 ,out_part_2 and so on if i have 1000 output files  the out_part_1000.

Comment: my files are created by split command like shivi11aa,shivi11ab,shivi11ac and so on.I just want to rename them

Comment: for i in 'ls -l shivi11a?'

Comment: @Shivani I updated my answer some 4 minutes ago. Did you not re-read it?  I also edited the question.  Please pay attention.

Comment: do j='expr $j +1;echo mv $i, output_part_$j;done

Comment: @Shivani, Please try the code snippet with a `for` loop in the beginning of Kusalananda's edited answer. We think it should work for you (if they are sorted in the correct order when the pattern `shivi11*` is expanded). If you want to check it before moving the files, put `echo ` in front of the `mv` command line.